# Repeater Checkboxes: How to Call a Method When Checked?

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, repeater

I have a Repeater control that has a list of strings as a datasource.  Each string is in a row along with a checkbox.  What is needed to make a checked checkbox call a method?  Right now, I am using OnCheckedChange, as seen below.

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDiffReport" runat="server"  >
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="clear: both; text-align: left; margin: 10px" 
                runat="server" Visible="<%# (Container.ItemIndex+1) == 0 %>">
                </div>
                 <%# Container.DataItem %>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" 
                 OnCheckedChange="rptSelectRow" Checked="false" 
                 AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="checkbox"  />
                    <br />
                    <hr />
             </ItemTemplate>
             ...
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: No errors thrown either on Visual Studio or on the client side via inspecting the webpage.  It reloads the page, but does not go into the method for the checkboxes when the OnCheckChanged event occurs.

Comment: check your `oncheckedchange` event name, Is it correct

Comment: Yes, rptSelectRow is correct.